# Cisco AnyConnect connection profiles affected by upgrades?

Tags: cisco-anyconnect

We are in the process of rolling out Cisco AnyConnect in our environment to replace the old IPSec client.  We are purposely avoiding this deployment to machines that already have the client installed (consultants, etc) in order to avoid any problems with their current installations.
I have received a report of someone who decided to go out and pull the software down from our software delivery catalog anyways.  It deleted his already existing connection profiles of external clients and it won't "remember" them now in the drop-down list of Cisco AnyConnect.

Does anyone have any experiences with Cisco AnyConnect and dealing with connection profiles for outside customers?  Any experiences of this happening where a software installation deletes them?

I'm trying to find a way to mitigate this.

thank you,

Geoff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AnyConnect and the old IPSec client are totally different beasts. AnyConnect provides a VPN over SSL/TLS and the other client uses IPSec.

The AnyConnect client does not leverage the same mechanism or any of the existing PCF files. So there should not have been any overwriting or deleting of config.

One of the advantages of the AnyConnect client is that it pulls its configuration down from the ASA based on tunnel-group/group-profile and any associated configuration files stored on the ASA in flash.

You should be able to have both clients installed simultaneously without any issues.